# passing data between page to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a poll in my web site and each poll have dynamic answer that this answer save to database i want to edit this answer

```
Answer an = new Answer();
var ans = an.ReadByByQid(Int64.Parse(ViewData["ID"].ToString()));
<div class="editor-label">
        Answer
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @foreach (var item in ans)
        {
            <input type="text" name="answer" value="@item.answere" /> 
        }
    </div>
```

i want get id of answer in controller to edit answer in database

Comment: Are you doing a form submit to read the answer from your textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the id in a hidden input and your form post data will have the `answerId` and you can access it in the action the same way you access the answer.

```
 Answer an = new Answer();
  var ans = an.ReadByByQid(Int64.Parse(ViewData["ID"].ToString()));
  <div class="editor-label">
        Answer
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @foreach (var item in ans)
        {
            <input type="text" name="answer" value="@item.answere" /> 
            <input type="hidden" id="answerId" value="@ans" /> 
        }
    </div>
```